# Is it safe to store the remote address of a DatagramPacket in the Channel AttributeMap in Netty?

Tags: java, netty

I have a UDP inbound connection. I need to know the address of the sender of the packet in one of the `ChannelHandler`s near the end of the pipeline. Is it safe/correct to store it in the channel's `AttributeMap`? Or do I risk the value from one packet being overwritten by a later packet before my handler can process it? Or is there a better/standard way to do this?

My first handler in the pipeline is basically just this:

```
public class DatagramToBytesInboundChannelHandler
    extends MessageToMessageDecoder<DatagramPacket> {

    public static final AttributeKey<InetSocketAddress> REMOTE_ADDRESS = 
        AttributeKey.newInstance( "UdpRemoteAddress" );

    @Override
    protected void decode( ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket msg,
        List<Object> out ) throws Exception {
        ctx.channel().attr( REMOTE_ADDRESS ).set( msg.sender() );
        out.add( msg.content().copy() );
    }
}
```

Then in a channel handler later (there are many, I'm just showing one of interest) in the pipeline, I need to retrieve it:

```
public class MyChannelHandler extends 
    SimpleChannelInboundHandler<MyMessage> {

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0( ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MyMessage msg ) {
        InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = ctx.channel().attr(
            REMOTE_ADDRESS ).getAndSet( null );
        // Do things with the remote address
    }
}
```

Is there any risk if I get two packets in quick succession, one from A and the next from B, that when `MyHandler` is processing the message from A that it will see the address from B?

Does the answer to this depend on my `Bootstrap` configuration at all?

Comment: Why not store it in `MyMessage`?

Comment: @EJP, I could, but it adds extra complexity to all of my other channel handlers. For example, these messages are Protobuf messages, so if I want to include the remote address in `MyMessage`, I can't use the ProtobufDecoder out of the box. I have to create my own handlers.